# How Google Cloud Platform validates iOS bundle ID?

Tags: ios, rest, google-cloud-platform, bundle-identifier

In Google Cloud Platform I can generate credentials to any Google service with iOS bundle ID restriction or SHA1 fingerprint for Android. To make a request to Google API I have to add the http header "X-Ios-bundle-indentifier". So how GCP validates that bundle? Bundle ID and API Key may be read from IPA by reverse engineering. Moreover bundle id is not private value.

Comment: I found this doc, Does [this](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/sendVerificationCode) help you and if you could provide more details it will be helpful.

Comment: Your link is about user email verification. I asked about client authorization (mobile app) in backend like Firebase.